# what is the type code for strings in python?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, data-structures

For initializing arrays in python we need type code for that .I need to store strings in that array.So what type code i should use ?

import array

array.array(typecode,['abc','fes','fsfs'])

Comment: Why don't you use a list?

Comment: Check out https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html

Comment: `array.array` does not support strings. You probably just want a `list` object

Comment: Probably he want to use c-style array

Answer (score 0):

for a shortcut, you used the one-line code

> array.array(str('u'), ['abc','fes','fsfs']

this code will help you out

Comment: It would be more helpfull of you extend your explanation.